# Make Java Run as Scheduled Task in XP - Problem in reading env user variable

Tags: java

I try to run a java application through scheduled task in XP :

```
at 11:00 /every:m,t,w,th,f,s,su cmd /c "C:\Projects\piko\dist\piko.jar" arg
```

I realize in piko.jar, it always read empty for

```
System.getProperty("user.home")
```

If I run it as normal application through command prompt,

java -jar C:\Projects\piko\dist\piko.jar arg

The environment variable is there.

May I know how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
cmd /c "java -jar C:\Projects\piko\dist\piko.jar arg"
```

Otherwise you probably have to specify a username and password to use when you schedule the task... it might be that XP is running it under some internal/system account which has no associated "user", per se.

Comment: I just scrap the usage of environment variable.